# WebSockets work without valid authorization token (Spring, SockJS, STOMP, OAuth)

Tags: spring-mvc, oauth, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I am integrating with WebSockets in my Spring MVC application. The authentication mechanism for my application is OAuth.

I was able to pass my OAuth token in connection string when connecting to SockJS:

```
var webSocketUrl = '/websocket' + '?access_token=' + auth.access_token;
var socket = new SockJS(webSocketUrl);
var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
```

Now I can send messages and subscribe to STOMP channels:

```
stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function(greeting){
        console.log(greeting);
    });

    stompClient.send("/app/hello", {}, JSON.stringify('John'));
});
```

In my backend I am able to get user principle injected to my STOMP controller methods (which means that Spring understands that there is an OAuth token in connection string):

```
@Controller
public class MyWebsocketsController {
    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public String greet(String name, Principal authorizedUser) {
        return "Hello, " + name + ", you have authorized as " + authorizedUser.getName();
    }
}
```

Now I would like to require user authorization on all messages and subscriptions, i.e. I would like to make sure that all calls to web sockets return 403 error code if no valid token was provided when connecting to SockJS.

I add this security configuration to my project:

```
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        messages
            .simpTypeMatchers(CONNECT, HEARTBEAT, UNSUBSCRIBE, DISCONNECT).permitAll()
            .simpDestMatchers("/app/**").authenticated()
            .simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/topic/**").authenticated()
            .simpTypeMatchers(MESSAGE, SUBSCRIBE).denyAll()
            .anyMessage().denyAll();
    }
}
```

But it does not seem to do the job. If I remove access token from connection string, I am still able to send messages to controller and to subscribe to channel.

```
// This stil works:
var webSocketUrl = '/websocket'; // + '?access_token=' + auth.access_token;
```

Of course, now I can't get the user principle in my controller, but except for this web sockets work fine.

I would appreciate any ideas how to make this thing work or any explanation why web sockets security configuration is not working for my case. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: This is really interesting, I hope we get an answer for this soon